# Google spreadsheet scripts, Server error occurred. Please try saving the project again

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been using the same scripts in my Google sheets for a few years and today when a sheet is copied the onOpen function to create a custom menu fails to appear.

If I attempt to run a function manually, I get an error, 'Server error occurred. Please try saving the project again.'

The problem seems to be affecting all of my sheets with custom scripts when copied, the existing sheet function still works fine.

Has anyone experienced this in the past 6 hours? Perhaps it is simply a Google server fault?

Comment: Having the same problem!

Comment: There are many reports of this issue. Currently there are several bugs raised in Google's bug tracker (e.g. Issue 67374469). Given that these problems occur on new or copied scripts, looks like an issue with authentication.

Comment: Did you enable the Drive API in Resources-> Advance Google Services?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we're not customer support for Google Apps Script. Reference [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/1595451). This kind of issues should be reported to the Google Apps Script Issue Tracker. See [Get Help | Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support)

Comment: Dean Ransevycz thanks this works!